# Java heap space con apache-poi en tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

Buenas,

cuando leo un fichero xlsx ejecutando mi programa contra el servidor de eclipse, lo lee y ejecuta sin problema, pero al generar el war y desplegarlo en un servidor tomcat me aparece un error de memoria (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded) a la hora de crear el objeto Workbook

```
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
```

¿alguna idea de por qué puede suceder esto solo cuando despliego en el servidor?

Gracias por adelantado.

La traza del error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createChunk(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:1935)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.ensureCapacity(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:1838)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createNode(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:1854)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createDeferredElement(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startElement(AbstractDOMParser.java:1067)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
at org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.readDocument(DocumentHelper.java:140)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:143)
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:183)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:175)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:438)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:403)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:190)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:296)
```

Comment: *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError* significa que se acabó la memoria disponible para el programa en ejecución. Compara el parámetro de memoria máxima de Tomcat con el del _servidor de eclipse_.

Comment: Al final el problema era el tamaño del excel, que etnia demasiadas pestañas ocultas.   Gracias.